# How to enable and disable my edit box on the checkbox clilck event

Tags: android

I am facing problem with enabling an edittext box at initialisation. I have disabled my editbox like so:  `text_edit.setFocusable(false);`

Later, I want to enable the textbox via the click of a checkbox.
The textbox is not being enabled, here is my click event code:

```
if(((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

    Toast.makeText(User_name_search .this, "Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    text_edit.setFocusable(false);
    //checkbox.setChecked(false);

} else {
    Toast.makeText(User_name_search .this, "Not Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    text_edit.setFocusable(true);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `setOnClickListener` or `setOnCheckedChangeListener` for the checkbox, and when somebody clicks, you should change `setfocusable`.

Comment: i have used  checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
      {
        
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to enable/disable the `EditText`, you should consider use the `setEnabled(boolean x)` method as described here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEnabled%28boolean%29 (`EditText` extends `TextView`).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following

```
Checkbox c1;
EditText e1;
click on check box c1 if

if(c1.isChecked==true)
{
e1.setEnabled(true);

} 
else
{
e1.setEnabled(false);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the click listener of the checkbox set the enabled property of the edittext to true. So if checkAbove is your checkbox and textAbove is your editText, the code will look like this..

```
checkAbove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        CheckBox temp = (CheckBox)view;
        if (temp.isChecked()){
            textAbove.setEnabled(true);
        }else {
            textAbove.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }
});
```

Also put

```
android:editable = "false"
```

for the textAbove view in the xml.